# WebStorm multiline comment has little bug?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, webstorm

I'm using Mac and when I press <kbd>Cmd + Shift + /</kbd> in order to comment multiple lines then `Help` Tab at the top occurs..

I don't want `Help` tab to be occurred.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: what is your system keyboard layout? please see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000616724-MacOS-The-shortcuts-work-unexpectedly-after-2017-1-update

Comment: qwerty for English and Korean. I'm using both to switch. I don't think this is problem. Is it?

Comment: I can comment multiline anyways but this bothers me a bit. I can't find solution from above url